# How to store every search term to Database in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a search form on my website. When the user types a query (like iPhone) the program will store that keyword to a database called "SearchTerms" with the number of people who searched for that keyword.

Example:

**search_term:** iPhone

**search_count:** 50

which means 50 peoples searched for the term "iPhone" on my website. I want the search term to be updated if the term exist, and added if the term does not exist.

Here's what I tried to do:

**models.py**

```
class SearchTerms(models.Model):
  search_terms = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
  total_searches = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

  search_objects = SearchTermManager()

  class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "Search Terms"

  def __str__(self):
    return self.search_terms
```

**views.py**

```
class SearchView(ListView):
    template_name = 'search.html'
    paginate_by = 20
    count = 0

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['count'] = self.count or 0
        context['query'] = self.request.GET.get('q')
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        request = self.request
        query = request.GET.get('q', None)

        if query is not None:
            product_results = Product.objects.search(query)

            # combine querysets
            queryset_chain = chain(
                    product_results
            )        
            qs = sorted(queryset_chain, 
                        key=lambda instance: instance.pk, 
                        reverse=True)
            self.count = len(qs) # since qs is actually a list
            return qs
        return Product.objects.none() # just an empty queryset as default
```

One more thing, is that I'm working with 2 tables. 
So when I type "iPhone" in the search form:

1. The term iPhone will be added to "SearchTerms" table (or increase value if already exist).
2. Search for that term in the "Products" table and display results.

I don't know how to work with 2 tables at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try like this using [**`get_or_create`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create):

```
class SearchView(ListView):
    template_name = 'search.html'
    paginate_by = 20
    count = 0
    queryset = Product.objects.none()

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['count'] = context.get('object_list').count()
        context['query'] = self.request.GET.get('q')
        return context

    def update_search_query(self, query):
      term, _ = SearchTerms.objects.get_or_create(
           defaults={'search_terms':query}, 
           search_terms__iexact=query
      )
      term.total_searches += 1
      term.save()

    def get_queryset(self):
        request = self.request
        query = request.GET.get('q', None)
        if query:
           self.update_search_query(query)
           return Product.objects.search(query).order_by('-pk')
        return super().get_queryset()
```

Here, I am reducing some of your code which are based on chaining and ordering, probably you don't need it, as you can order the result using `order_by`. Then I also added a code for getting the count. In context, you will get the queryset from key `object_list`, I am using [**`count`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#count) method to fetch the number of result.

Comment: thanks a lot of your code :) works well. Really appreciate it :)